# Page breaks within a multi-nested RDLC report on VS 2013

Tags: visual-studio, pdf, pagination, report, rdlc

I'm having difficulty getting a tablix to page break appropriately.  This is, currently, set as a subreport within a main report page.  The problem child is a childgroup within a parent group.  The parent group of the tablix is too small to reach page borders, and is grouped by client / document ID.  The child group of the same tablix contains data of client's properties grouped by property ID. This child group exceeds page boarders, and gets truncated mid-row (Horizontal formatting is all under control).

I've already set all cells within the table to "KeepTogether = False" in advanced mode. I tried using a parallel group to the child group, grouping by a row count (if I insert a page break every 24 or 30 rows from the child group, it'll fix it).  But VS says I cannot use an aggregate within a group.  And I've tried playing with replacing the child group with another subreport. And ran into another batch of trouble there. I hope this is a sufficiently detailed question. Thanks for your time!!!!

Comment: If I could execute a count () of productID, I could get around this pagination problem, by breaking at a specific number. But VS states that I can't execute any aggregate functions within a group clause.